# How to get axios error response INTO the redux saga catch method

Tags: axios, redux-saga

With axios the code is:

```
export const createBlaBla = (payload) => {
  return axios.post('/some-url', payload)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(err => err);
}
```

And then I'm using this with redux-saga like this:

```
function* createBlaBlaFlow(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(createBlaBla, action.payload);
    if (response) {
      yield put({
        type: CREATE_BLA_BLA_SUCCESS
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // I need the error data here ..
    yield put({
      type: CREATE_BLA_BLA_FAILURE,
      payload: 'failed to create bla-bla'
    });
  }
}
```

In case of some error on the backend - like invalid data send to the backend - it returns a 400 response with some data:

```
{
  "code":"ERR-1000",
  "message":"Validation failed because ..."
  "method":"POST",
  "errorDetails":"..."
}
```

But I don't receive this useful data in the `catch` statement inside the saga. I can console.log() the data in the axios `catch` statement, also I can get it inside the `try` statement in the saga, but it never arrives in the `catch`.

Probably I need to do something else? ... Or the server shouldn't return 400 response in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I came up with two solutions of this problem.

===

First one - very dump workaround, but actually it can be handy in some specific cases.

In the saga, right before we call the function with the axios call inside, we have a variable for the errors and a callback that sets that variable:

```
let errorResponseData = {};
const errorCallback = (usefulErrorData) => {
    errorResponseData = usefulErrorData;
};
```

Then - in the axios method we have this:

```
export const createBlaBla = (payload, errCallback) => {
    return axios.post('/some-url', payload)
        .then(response => response)
        .catch(err => {
            if (err && err.response.data && typeof errCallback === 'function') {
                errCallback(err.response.data);
            }
            return err;
        });
}
```

This way, when we make request and the backend returns errors - we'll call the callback and will provide the errors from the backend there. This way - in the saga - we have the errors in a variable and can use it as we want.

===

However, another solution came to me from another forum.

The problem I have is because in the method with the axios call I have `catch`, which means that the errors won't bubble in the generator. So - if we modify the method with the axios call like this:

```
export const createBlaBla = (payload) => {
  return axios.post('/some-url', payload)
}
```

Then in the `catch` statement in the saga we'll have the actual backend error.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Comment: The second solution did the job for me. I was just missing a `return`. Tysm!!

Answer (score 1):

In your API call you can do the following:

```js
const someAPICall = (action) => {
  return axios.put(`some/path/to/api`, data, {
    withCredentials: true,
    validateStatus: (status) => {
      return (status == 200 || status === 403);
    }
  });
};
```

Please note the `validateStatus()` part - this way when axios will encounter `200` or `403` response, it will not throw Error and you will be able to process the response after

```js
const response = yield call(someAPICall, action);
if (response.status === 200) {
  // Proceed further
} else if (response.status === 403) {
  // Inform user about error
} else {
  ...
}
```